# What is the purpose when assign a named function to a different variable name?

Tags: javascript

**Just to carify**, I'm not asking the difference of function declaration and function variable.

For example:

```
var Klass = function() {};
Klass.prototype._fn1 = function fn1() {};
Klass.prototype._fn2 = function fn2() {};
```

So, my question is what is the purpose of doing this? **Why** can't just write:

```
var Klass = function() {};
Klass.prototype._fn1 = function() {}; // <-- note that the function has no name, it just be assigned to the object as a property
Klass.prototype._fn2 = function() {};
```

Comment: It provides a way for the inner scope to access itself locally. Otherwise, there's no reason I can think of

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript

Comment: @Boaz How does that have to do with naming the function?

Comment: He's not asking about OO, he's asking about the name `fn` in the expression `function fn()`

Comment: Check the duplicated question, there are several answers and at least 1 is what you are looking for

Comment: @Ian You are right. Removed my comment. It was posted before the OP's edit.

Answer (score -1):

Basically this means you are adding the method `_fn1()`  to `Klass` Constructor.

```
Klass.prototype._fn1 = function fn1() {};
```

And this method is available over the object which is made by using `Klass()` Constructor.

```
myObj = new Klass();
myObj._fn1() //you can access the method like this
```

Comment: you forgot the dot, myObj._fn1()

Comment: But what is the purpose of the name `fn1`? That's what his question is asking.

Comment: I.e. why isn't it `Klass.prototype._fn1 = function() {}`?